# Converting Hive Map to Redshift JSON

Tags: json, dictionary, hive, amazon-redshift

Can anyone recommend a code snippet, script, tool for converting a Hive Map field to a Redshift JSON field?

I have a Hive table that has two Map fields and I need to move the data to Redshift.  I can easily move the data to a string format but then lose some functionality with that.  Would prefer to have Map ported to JSON to maintain key, value pairs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the *to_json* UDF 
http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/